# Inequality involving size of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I’m following my professor’s notes, and I became confused by an inequality he used without justification, but I cannot see why it is true. Any help is appreciated.

Let $\{T_t\}_t$ be a sequence of iid, positive, integer-valued random variables. Suppose $$P\{T \ge x \} = \Theta \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\right). $$

What I do not understand is he then states:

$$(1) \max_{1 \leq i \leq t} T_i = \Theta (t^2),$$
$$ (2) \sum_{i=1}^t T_i = \Theta (t^2), $$

both in probability. I would appreciate help on how he concluded both of these from the previous fact.

Thank you!

Comment: So (1) and (2) lead to the same expression?

Comment: #1 is the more straightforward scenario: the max is less than something if and only if all of them are less than that thing, so the CDF of the max evaluated at some $c$ will be like $\left ( 1-\Theta(1/\sqrt{c}) \right )^t$, which is like $1$ if $t \ll \sqrt{c}$ and is like $0$ if $t \gg \sqrt{c}$. Thus it is in its intermediate range if $t \sim \sqrt{c}$. Note that this can be done in exactly the same way if you had a $\Theta(x^p)$ estimate for any $p<0$, in this case you would have $t \sim c^{-p}$.

Comment: #2 is at first glance more subtle because you have to consider the possibility that a large number of terms, say $\Theta \left ( t^\alpha \right )$ of them for some $0<\alpha \leq 1$ are at least of the order $\Theta \left ( t^\beta \right )$ for some $0<\beta<2$, in which case the sum would be of the order of $\Theta \left ( t^{\alpha+\beta} \right )$ and in principle it could be that $\alpha+\beta > 2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say $ a/\sqrt{x} \le P(T \ge x) \le b/\sqrt{x}$ for $x$ sufficiently large.
For (1):
$$ P\left(\max_{1\le i \le t} T_i < c t^2\right) =  P(T < c t^2)^t $$
When $c > 0$, for $t$ sufficiently large this is between $(1 - a/(\sqrt{c} t))^t$
and $(1 - b/(\sqrt{c} t))^t$, which as $t \to \infty$ go to $\exp(-a/\sqrt{c})$ and
$\exp(-b/\sqrt{c})$ respectively.  Thus for any $\epsilon > 0$, taking $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $\exp(-a/\sqrt{c_1}) < \epsilon$ and $\exp(-b/\sqrt{c_2}) > 1-\epsilon$, we find that
$P\left(\max_{1\le i \le t} T_i < c_1 t^2\right) < \epsilon$
while  $P\left(\max_{1\le i \le t} T_i < c_2 t^2\right) > 1-\epsilon$.

Comment: +1, just pointing out that you didn't comment on the second case in the question.

Comment: Thank you! I didn’t accept the answer yet, just due to 2 missing but if isn’t eventually solved I will give it to you